# how to open file with chinese name by using powershell script

Tags: powershell

if I opened powershell and typed `D:\工作日志.xlsx` ,press `Enter`,then the excel file was opened.
but if I typed `D:\工作日志.xlsx` and saved it as .ps1 script file,it occured a error after running it.
the error information was liked "can not recognize the command “D:\骞?LIMS浜嬩笟閮?鏋楁瀯閿?宸ヤ綔鏃ュ織.xlsx”".
Is it because of the encoding?
How to fix this problem?

Comment: `& 'D:\工作日志.xlsx'` should open it. It's just as the exception mentions, it's being read as a command and not a file path. You may also use `Start-Process`.

Comment: `start-process "D:\工作日志.xlsx"`  doesn't work. `system can not find the file with name "D:\骞?LIMS浜嬩笟閮?鏋楁瀯閿?宸ヤ綔鏃ュ織.xlsx"`.

Comment: Did `& 'D:\工作日志.xlsx'` work?

Comment: `& 'D:\工作日志.xlsx'` still doesn't work,

Comment: However,`D:\test.xlsx` work.

Answer (score 0):

the problem has been solved after I installed the newer version powershell.
the previous version(the problem version)'s `$PSVersionTable` was 5.1.19041.1023,and `$OutputEncoding` was `US-ASCII`

the newer version's `$PSVersionTable` was 7.1.3,and `$OutputEncoding` was `UTF-8`

anyway,thanks for Abraham Zinala's reply!